# How to enable actions on toggle selected items

Tags: javascript, python, html, toggle

I'm developing an Admin Panel on a website (Python + Flask) and I came across with an issue while trying to implement a *Select All toggle*.

The table looks like the following:

[image]

The toggle itself has been implemented but now I want to make it useful.

Upon clicking the 'SELECTED' button I want to be able to delete each and every selected item (flag) but I'm not exacly sure how I can pull it off.

Each flag can be individually deleted by clicking on the *glyphicon-trash* according to the following Python/HTML:

```
<button onclick="deleteSelected('politician')">SELECTED</button>
{% for flag in flags %}
  <tr>
    <!-- Check box -->
    <td style="width: 60px;"><input type="checkbox" name="politician" value="bar1"></td>
    <!-- First Name -->
    <td class="col-title">{{flag.flagtitle}}</td>
    <!-- Last Name -->
    <td class="col-description">{{flag.flagreason}}</td>
    <!-- Details -->
    <td>
      <a href="/flag/{{ flag.idflag }}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
      </a>
    </td>
    <!-- Edit icon -->
    <td class="list-buttons-column">
      <a href="/politician/{{ flag.politician }}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
      </a>
    </td>

    <!-- DELETE ITEM/FLAG -->
    <td class="col-delete">
      <form action ="/delete_flag/{{ flag.idflag }}" method="POST">
        <button onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this flag?');">
          <span class="fa fa-trash glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
        </button>
      </form>
    </td>

  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

My idea was to develop a JavaScript function to delete the selected content but I'm not sure how I can get the `flag.idFlag`, which is the flags' id's associated.

I thought it would look something like this:

```
function deleteSelected(elem) {
     checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(elem);
     for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
       if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
             delete((checkboxes[i].getSelectedFlag).idFlag)
       }
     }
}
```

Obviously the code above doesn't work, it was just meant to give you an idea of what I'm looking for.

Is there a way I can do this? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Ok so I figured it out. Considering I had to submit multiple forms where `action="/delete_flag/flag.idFlag"`, I added a column to the table where the flag's id would be visible. Like the following:

[image]

For that matter, I created a JS function to retrieve the first value of each row (ID) and store it in an array of IDs so that I could create and submit a form for each one of them.

For each ID of the array I create a form where `form.action = "/delete_flag/" + retrievedID`. See code below.

```
function deleteRecords() {
    var arrayOfIDs;
    arrayOfIDs = $('#table-style').find('[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function(){
            return $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
        }).get();   

        var delFlagForm = document.createElement("form");
        var action; 
        var formID;
        var submitFormStr;

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            action = "/delete_flag/" + arr[i];
            formID = 'form' + i;
            delFlagForm.setAttribute("id", formID);
            delFlagForm.setAttribute("method", "post");
            delFlagForm.setAttribute("action", action);

            delFlagForm.submit(); 
        }
}
```

This sounded good in my head until I realised multiple form submissions will only work asynchronously. **So I made the following changes and this is where I'm stuck right now**. The forms simply won't be submitted, nothing happens:

```
function deleteRecords() {
    var arraryOfIDs;
    arraryOfIDs = $('#table-style').find('[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function(){
            return $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
        }).get();   

        var delFlagForm = document.createElement("form");
        var action; 
        var formID;
        var submitFormStr;

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            action = "/delete_flag/" + arr[i];
            formID = 'form' + i;
            delFlagForm.setAttribute("id", formID);
            delFlagForm.setAttribute("method", "post");
            delFlagForm.setAttribute("action", action);

            if (i != 0) submitFormStr += ' #' + formID;
            else submitFormStr = '#' + formID; 
        }
        $('submitFormStr').submit();
        return false;
}
```

The variable `submitFormStr` updated within the loop stores the id for each form created like the following: `#form0 #form1`so for this reason I don't understand why the piece of code `$('submitFormStr').submit();` which is equivalent to `$('#form0 #form1').submit();` is not working.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out. Considering I had to submit multiple forms where `action="/delete_flag/flag.idFlag"`, I added a column to the table where the flag's id would be visible. Like the following:

[image]

For that matter, I created a JS function to retrieve the first value of each row (ID) and store it in an array of IDs so that I could create and submit a form for each one of them.

For each ID of the array I create a form where `form.action = "/delete_flag/" + retrievedID`. See code below.

```
function deleteRecords() {
    var arrayOfIDs;
    arrayOfIDs = $('#table-style').find('[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function(){
            return $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
        }).get();   

        var delFlagForm = document.createElement("form");
        var action; 
        var formID;
        var submitFormStr;

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            action = "/delete_flag/" + arr[i];
            formID = 'form' + i;
            delFlagForm.setAttribute("id", formID);
            delFlagForm.setAttribute("method", "post");
            delFlagForm.setAttribute("action", action);

            delFlagForm.submit(); 
        }
}
```

This sounded good in my head until I realised multiple form submissions will only work asynchronously. **So I made the following changes and this is where I'm stuck right now**. The forms simply won't be submitted, nothing happens:

```
function deleteRecords() {
    var arraryOfIDs;
    arraryOfIDs = $('#table-style').find('[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function(){
            return $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
        }).get();   

        var delFlagForm = document.createElement("form");
        var action; 
        var formID;
        var submitFormStr;

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            action = "/delete_flag/" + arr[i];
            formID = 'form' + i;
            delFlagForm.setAttribute("id", formID);
            delFlagForm.setAttribute("method", "post");
            delFlagForm.setAttribute("action", action);

            if (i != 0) submitFormStr += ' #' + formID;
            else submitFormStr = '#' + formID; 
        }
        $('submitFormStr').submit();
        return false;
}
```

The variable `submitFormStr` updated within the loop stores the id for each form created like the following: `#form0 #form1`so for this reason I don't understand why the piece of code `$('submitFormStr').submit();` which is equivalent to `$('#form0 #form1').submit();` is not working.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?